# How to loop over pages in API response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to save API response to database and that's why I have to loop over all pages from API response. I read some related topics, unfortunately I can't make 2 things: extract number of pages from response header and then loop through all pages to save data to db. I looked into `response.Headers` but there's no info about total pages. I hardcoded total number of pages in a loop (method `SaveData`) but it doesn't work at all. This is what I got now:

**CallAPI**

```cs
private static async Task<T> CallAPI<T>(string endpoint, string accessToken)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
    new Uri(ApiUri, endpoint));

    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var responseObject = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(responseStream);

    //var res_header = response.Headers  //none of its elements include total number of pages

    return responseObject;
}
```

**SaveData**

```cs
private static async Task SaveData(string accessToken)
{
    MSSQL_Conn conn = new MSSQL_Conn(conn_string);

    // here I hardcoded total number of pages (=5) but at the end I'd like to pass here
    // the number of pages from API response
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       var result = await CallAPI<GetTrips>($"trips?page={i}", accessToken);

       var trips = tripsAPI.items?.Select(s => new Trips
          {
            TripID = s.id,
            VehicleId = s.vehicle
          });
    
       // some code that writes data to db...
    }

}
```

`GetTrips` is a class where I store API response, `trips` is an endpoint, `Trips` is a model class where I store some chosen data from API.

**EDIT:** this is `GetTrips` class with `page` etc. fields where API response is stored:

```
    public class GetTrips
    {
        public int page { get; set; }
        public int page_size { get; set; }
        public Item[] items { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item
    {
     ...
     }
```

Comment: The ActionResult from a controller is the data in the body of the response.  Not the header.  You need to look at the contents of the response which is a string containing all the text in the response to see if you are getting more than one row of data back from the database.  The class <T> should have a list object with all the rows of data from the database.  If you do not have a list object you will only get one row of data in your controller.

Comment: I added `GetTrips` model class where API response is stored. If I return `page` field than I can see value=1 as it's the first page of data.

Comment: What is multiple pages?  A request is one message and a response is one message.  Neither have multiple pages.  Do not get the transport layer mixed up with the application layer.  The transport layer can break message into pieces but the request/response you only see a single combined message.